# Event for "DataContextChanging"?

Tags: wpf, datacontext

I am very new to WPF so forgive me if the question doesn't make sense. Is there an event that is fired before data context change? I want to commit the pending data changes before the data context is switched away.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is no `DataContextChanging` event, but the `DataContextChanged` event provides the old value of the `DataContext`:

```
private void Window_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    object oldDataContext = e.OldValue;
    ...
}
```

Comment: The delegate is a bit different for windows runtime. The args is DataContextChangedEventArgs , and it doesn't have an oldValue property. What would be the equievalent ?

Comment: @bahti, I don't know... I'm not sure there *is* an equivalent

Answer (score 3):

There is no such event, if you want to make sure data is saved or that the user can choose to abort edits you should look into [navigational](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx) architectures where screens are changed in a managed way.